# Add horizontal spacing before text

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I want to write this type of code.:

```
const uint8_t channelMap [][3]  = {{vplus_0 ,GND_0,vminus_0},
                                    {vplus_1 ,GND_1,vminus_1},
                                    {vplus_2 ,GND_2,vminus_2},
```

so the horizontal spacing i have tried some tricks but it isn't working.
Please help how can I give this much spacing .

Comment: `\begin{verbatim}`......`\end{verbatim}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using '\verb|text|' inside tabular environment might be what your'e looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        \verb|const uint8_t channelMap [][3]| & = & \verb|{{vplus_0 ,GND_0,vminus_0},| \\
                                              &   & \verb| {vplus_1 ,GND_1,vminus_1},| \\
                                              &   & \verb| {vplus_2 ,GND_2,vminus_2},| \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Producing

[image: Verb inside tabular environment]

Comment: No problem, if this is the solution you were looking for you can accept it as answer and/or upvote it.